# How to sort values Alphabetically in php on click

Tags: php, php-7

I have a parent class which is loading the data from Dataset. Child class is accessing the values and printing them in a table. There are 10 rows with name, surname and more. I would like to sort name values when someone click on name `<th>` using plain php without any javascript or mysql.
Here is my code

```
$table = "<table border='1'>" .
         "<tr>" . "<th>" . "ID" . "</th>";
         "<th>" . "<button id='name'>" .  "Name" . "</button>" .  "</th>" .
         "<th>" . "Surname" . "</th>" .
         "<th>" . "Active" . "</th>" .
         "<th>" . "Last Login" . "</th>" .
         "<th>" . "Picture" . "</th>" .
         "<th>" . "<button id='rating'>" .  "Rating" . "</button>" ."</th>" . "</tr>";
        echo $table;
        //showing the data in rows
        foreach ($user_data as $data) {
            echo "<tr>" . "<td>" . $data->id . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $data->name . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $data->surname . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $data->active . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $data->last_login . "</td>";
```

**Note:**
I don't want to introduce new loop. I want to stay in one loop.

Comment: why not using `sort($user_data);` before the `foreach` ?

Comment: actually its different I would like to sort them on `<th` tag click.  in your case it will sort all values. i want everything to stay as it is except name. on click name values should sort by asc and then clicking again it should sort by desc

Answer (score 0):

You can use sorting. But what you are asking for is already been covered in Datatables API. You can use the JS framework Datatables API and then make a cleaner back-end program to handle the API with a post request.
If you want to do it from scratch I suggest you go for Jquery event handling with sorting or do a API trigger with sorting.

Comment: I have mentioned in my question. I cannot use any `JS` or mysql

Comment: Then is more easy @QasimAli just add the datatables framwork and use it easily. You can at least attach a JS in your code.